# Remove status bar without making Navigation Bar shorter Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, statusbar

I'm making an app in which I have a navigation bar that contains a custom background image. It looks like this.

[image: Image of NavBar with Status bar]

I want to remove the status bar (as it covers part of the Nav Bar image), however when I do it shortens the NavBar, like so:

[image: Image of NavBar without Status bar]

I want to find a way to get rid of the status bar without shortening the nav bar and causing the image in the navBar to come all out of proportion.

Here is the code I use to set the background image of the NavBar.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBar"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Thanks!

Edit: Please note that I attempted to just change the height of the Navigation Bar, however the background image remained out of proportion.

Comment: I tried changing the height of the Navigation bar but the background image still was out of proportion.

Comment: updated an answer for you, your question was unclear to me until now.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImageView *logoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourLogoImage"]];
[logoImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f, 44.0f)];

logiImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;

self.navigationItem.titleView = logoImageView ;
```

Will fix your UIImage stretching.

**EDIT:**

or

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.titleView = logoImageView;
```

Comment: This did not work for me. Could it be because there is also a tab bar controller embedded within the navigation controller?

Comment: @Nshweky I edited it for you to make it more clear my head is in slowmotion atm